# What exactly is the scope of Access Violation '0xc0000005'?

Tags: windows, winapi, exception

I was wondering about exception 0xc0000005 and what it acctually encompasses.

I.e. I take it this occurs if an application tries to access freed memory/memory belonging to another process.
But what about, for example, an address mapped for hardware? Or an address outside the valid range? Do attempted accesses to these fault with the same code or do they have their own?
Does this include failed reads to valid addresses owned by the process?

Essentially I want to know when an application fails with this exception, what may have gone wrong; is this a narrow fault that could only have come from the apps. code or am I looking at anything up and including hardware problems?

(I know there must be an MSDN page on this but searching Google or MSDN brings up the expected 100 pages of troubleshooting random applications ;))

Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to read the processor manual to drill this down.  It is triggered by a "trap", best described as an exception in the processor.  A trap interrupts code execution and lets an operating system "catch" handler deal with the fault.  A very common benign one is a page fault, raised when the processor tries to read data from RAM that isn't mapped yet.  That's how virtual memory is implemented.

An AccessViolation belongs to a group of traps that are hard faults that the operating system doesn't know how to handle.  It is called "General Protection Fault" in the processor manual.  It's a bit of a grab-bag, there are lots of ways to trigger a GPF.  By far the most common one is trying to read memory that isn't mapped, usually caused by heap memory corruption.  Followed by trying to execute a machine code instruction that isn't valid or can only be executed by privileged code, usually caused by stack memory corruption.

These traps are as nasty as they come, the processor simply cannot continue executing the program.  The operating system certainly doesn't know how to handle it, it raises an AccessViolation exception to give the program a shot at jerking the processor back to known-good code.  Possible by using the `__try/__except` keywords in your code.  Not a great idea btw, other than for custom error reporting, you have no real idea how the state of your program got mutated before it died and thus no way to restore it back.

Without such an SEH handler, this ends up in a backstop that Windows provides.  You can provide your own with [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634(v=vs.85).aspx), useful to customize the crash report.  The system-provided one puts an end to it by triggering WER, the Windows Error Reporting component.  Which ultimately terminates the process.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and precise explanation. I was not aware it originated from the processor itself, it makes more sense thinking about it like that. 'as nasty as they come' Indeed! I wonder how long it will be before processors start to feed useful information back when these exceptions/traps/interrupts are triggered?

Answer (score 23):

First, you need to understand that addresses in a user-mode process are virtual addresses.  They are not the actual addresses used to access hardware.  Rather, there is a virtual-to-physical translation circuit in the CPU (part of the memory management unit) which finds a matching entry in the "Translation Lookaside Buffer".  During each context switch, the OS fills the TLB with the memory mappings belonging to your process.

So there is no way to try to access memory belonging to other processes, nor can you try to access hardware.  It's not that this access is detected and fails, it's that no mapping exists for memory that does not belong to your program.

If your program accesses an address that does not map to anywhere, a trap will occur as Hans said.  It's the same trap for "page faults" and "access violations".  First the OS will check if the address is valid but not in the TLB (for example, your PC ran out of memory and some was swapped out to disk).  In that case the OS will move the data back into physical RAM, set the proper mapping in the TLB, and continue running your program.  If the OS determines that the address is completely invalid (there's no swap location associated with it), it will generate an "access violation" (Windows naming) or "segmentation fault" (POSIX naming).

Usually the cause is a logic bug, but if you had e.g. a RAM failure that changed a bit in one of your pointers, the hardware failure could trigger an access violation also.

Comment: Thank you for the description of the workings of the TLB, its very helpful in understanding how these exceptions occur. I find all these technical details very interesting, though I feel very foolish now for the user model i've had so far of the architecture being just a big version of that of the far simpler processors i'm used to working with. I'll try and find an x86 manual so I can understand it properly.

Answer (score -1):

I got [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/06/03/access-violation-how-dare-you.aspx) as my first result for "access violation" (no quotes) on google. I'm not sure of the specifics, but an AV just means that: the processor tried to read from or write to a particular address that its current state did not allow. It could be a hardware issue, a bus error, unmapped virtual memory, bad CPU; pretty much anything that indicates violating access protections.

Comment: Usually caused by software bugs.