# VB.NET crashing exception (0xC0000005)

Tags: vb.net, crash

I rename a VB.NET 2010 project and the IDE crash over and over.
I open another project and same result, after a few seconds or if I open Form1.vb the IDE crash.

And the worst part is there's no info about on the Error window.
The only that I can see as an error code is 0xC0000005

Is the only program crashing on my PC so I have my doubts about a hardware issue.

How can I figure out what is happening?

Can somebody give any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried googling?

Comment: Yes, and all that I find is the same error code but related to an application, not to the IDE itself.

Answer (score 1):

First off, take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303524/what-exactly-is-the-scope-of-access-violation-0xc0000005) where the answer does a good job of explaining the OXC0000005 error, and all that it encompasses.

Second, look at what has changed on your system since the last time you were able to successfully run Visual Studio. I have seen a few cases where a bad windows update was the cause of a user receiving this error. If you have installed updates since the last time you were able to run VS without error, you may want to uninstall those updates and try VS again. If VS works, begin to re-install the updates 1-by-1, testing VS between every update, to determine which update caused the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I turn off the PC, physically clean the RAM with isopropyl alcohol and now the IDE is running since about 15 minutes with no errors. I don't know if because I restart the PC or was the cleaning of the RAM that make it work. I hope this works and this does not happen again.