# Can Ada be told not to catch EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: c++, windows, ada, gnat

We have a large Ada/C++ system (using Gnatpro 7.3.2) running on Windows which very rarely crashes hard with a 0xC0000005 windows memory violation.  I've tried to simplify by creating a small Ada program which calls a C++ library, and the library tries to write to address 0x07.  But in this case, instead of getting the expected C0000005, the Ada subsystem reports a PROGRAM ERROR with the message EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION and a nice stack trace.

Having to find this rare bug, I first wrote a C++ program writing to address 7, which caused a C000005 as expected, but this uses the MSVC runtime.  My small Ada program shows different behaviour.  Is it possible to disable the Ada runtime layer that catches the memory violation?

Comment: You would probably have to modify the run-time to do that.  If you have a support contract with AdaCore, you could ask them, if they can help you.

Comment: I guess you have some memory corruption somewhere. If the stack is corrupted, very bad things can happen when an exception is raised because it can fail and generate other errors while unwinding the stack. Check for C++ objects which are freed and still used by your Ada code.

Comment: You’re using GNAT Pro, don’t you have a support contract?

Answer (score 0):

You're actually asking a couple of different questions here:

1. Q: What is the difference between a (Windows) 0xc0000005 access violation, and an Ada  PROGRAM ERROR/EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION?
2. Q: What can I do about it in my Ada application?

To better understand 0xc0000005, look here:

[What exactly is the scope of Access Violation '0xc0000005'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303524/what-exactly-is-the-scope-of-access-violation-0xc0000005)

To deal with the Ada program error, why not just use a standard Ada "exception" block, for example:

```
with Ada.Exceptions;  use Ada.Exceptions;
...
exception
  when Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION =>
    Put ("Access Violation: ");
    Put_Line (Exception_Name (Error));
    Put (Exception_Message (Error));
  when Error: others =>
    Put ("Something Else: ");
    Put_Line (Exception_Information(Error));
end;
```

Comment: (1) `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` isn’t an Ada exception, (2) OP’s problem is they get an E.A.V. _instead of_ a `Program_Error` (which _is_ an Ada exception).