# Access Violation when returning a value calling a C++ dll function from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I'm trying to make a call from C# to a c++ function in a DLL. One argument of this function is a pointer to a short type variable.

I'm not doing any fancy data structure, or unknown-sized variables. Just a simple short value.

When the DLL c++ function tries to modify the value of this variable, it gives an "Unmanaged exception 0xC0000005: Access Violation".

I cannot modify the DLL source (it's used in other projects and I cannot touch it, though I have the source code to debug it)

**Code of the c++ DLL function** (please note the "//this line provokes the exception" comment line in the code)

```cpp
// declaration
virtual TestFunction(short __RPC_FAR *sRet) = 0;

// definition
STDMETHODIMP CABTest::TestFunction(short *sReturnValue)
{
    //some
    //calculations
    //here
    *sReturnValue = 1; //this line provoques the exception
    return 0;
}
```

**C# code invoking the DLL**

```
[DllImport("test.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern short TestFunction(ref short sReturn);

short sMyValue = 0;
TestFunction(ref sMyValue);
```

I would expect sMyValue to value 1, as the reference I'm passing is a straight short type (not a fancy data struct) but I only get an app crash (the above exception).

What can I do in the C# code to avoid this problem? All I've seen searching for similar questions required rewriting the C++ functions (changing "short *sReturnValue" for "short **sReturnValue" but I cannot touch the original DLL source code.

I think I will write a wrapper.dll that invokes the test.dll but I was wondering if there was any direct and faster solution.

Comment: Are you sure `CABTest::TestFunction(short*)` is a static member function? Wan we see the declaration of the function? (the `.h`)

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303524/what-exactly-is-the-scope-of-access-violation-0xc0000005#5303952

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk certainly not.

Comment: What is the value of `*sReturnValue`? Isn't it maybe a problem of writing to shared memory?

Comment: Maybe relevant : http://www.codingvision.net/security/c-read-write-another-process-memory

Comment: Don't bother: it's certainly `TestFunction` expecting a `CABTest` instance. VTC as incomplete question.

Comment: virtual /* [helpstring][id] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE TestFunction( 
            /* [retval][out] */ short __RPC_FAR *sRet) = 0;

Comment: Whao! `virtual` function! Are you sure you want to call this from a C# application?

Comment: The function in the C++ dll looks as been autogenerated with the VC6 assistant (right click, create new method...)

Comment: @PtolomeoXII The C++ code you posted isn't adding up IMO.  You have a virtual function, which requires an instance of `CABTest`, yet there is no mention of creating a `CABTest` instance in your C# code to be used by the C++ DLL.  I could understand if `TestFunction` were a simple `C` exported, "free" function, but it isn't.  I agree that this question is incomplete.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to instance CABTest and seems to work. 
I thought I just could use the DLL to use just the functions that I needed, silly me.

Answer (score 0):

I created an instance as @PaulMcKenzie suggests and it's working fine.
I erroneously thought that I could just grab the DLL and use the calculation functions needed but I guess I couldn't.
Just leaving this answer for others that might make the same mistake.