After converting .exe file from .py file with pyinstaller and executed, immadiatelly closing, throws Event Viewer log MSVCP140.dll
My python application is working truly on using python debugger on visual studio code environment. After converting exe file with this coomand dont working and closing immediatelly!
I tried :

install vc_redist.exe from Microsoft website.
checking firewall or defender issues
writing manually print() and created log.txt file to manually examine what is going on This show me mysql.connector problem can be occour because do not connects mysql with exe but i dont know why

Pyinslatter command ->
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --hidden-import=modulename --name "TemperedGlass" .\main.py

Event Viewr Error Log ->
Faulting application name: TemperedGlass.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x673de59f
Faulting module name: MSVCP140.dll, version: 14.26.28720.3, time stamp: 0x5e74aeb6
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000012ea0
Faulting process id: 0x3B70
Faulting application start time: 0x1DB3B5130BCE267
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Leno\Desktop\Projects\Tempered_Glass\dist\TemperedGlass.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Users\Leno\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI122402\PyQt5\Qt5\bin\MSVCP140.dll
Report Id: 90ca7cc5-3781-4834-9567-5bb3392573d7
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 

Event Viewer Information Log ->
Fault bucket 1734448491948551848, type 4
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: TemperedGlass.exe
P2: 0.0.0.0
P3: 673de59f
P4: MSVCP140.dll
P5: 14.26.28720.3
P6: 5e74aeb6
P7: c0000005
P8: 0000000000012ea0
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.f105b877-58c9-458d-9b1b-b1d9a6e9384e.tmp.dmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.b485e6a6-1d98-44d8-b624-d05fbf022ef5.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.15f8a9ec-d964-4f8f-b57e-6c5e3af9e64c.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.4606f1cd-cfb3-4fe5-a79b-d9d4dc629c37.tmp.txt
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.f7f481fb-8c1c-4bfa-9733-abe801fe4568.tmp.xml

These files may be available here:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_TemperedGlass.ex_514472413dbd89759f5d9bff3ebad77f74d3de9_568cca06_aa4083a4-f608-4838-a396-3206cc37b19e

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 90ca7cc5-3781-4834-9567-5bb3392573d7
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: 09f02d07b7b753d9d811ffb6c3ce2ea8
Cab Guid: 0


Does it work if you "run as administrator"?  Application Error 0xc0000005 is an "Access Violation". Note, if you happen not to know EXACTLY what this program does, don't do this to "fix it".

@JonSG ı tried to execute with "run as administrator" but still throw same error and information on event log and yes I know the application what is doing because ı wroted. Do you know any particular reason to throw this!

This talks a bit about what but is likely not helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303524/what-exactly-is-the-scope-of-access-violation-0xc0000005

@JonSG thanks for sharing. That caught my interest. And ı think this not because of my hand writed codes. İt likes PyQt library error due to my fault. I will write more info to log.txt file to determine which lines.

@JonSG interestiing but ı soolved. I changed mysql.connector library to PyMySql and it worked. Thanks for the support
